`undefined symbol: __libc_unwind_link_get, version GLIBC_PRIVATE` when running Python program to save svg as hpgl file using Inkscape
I'm using Inkscape to save an SVG file as an HPGL file. I believe HPGL runs a Python script to do this. However, this Python script is failing with the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hpgl_output.py", line 23, in <module>
    import inkex
  File "/tmp/.mount_InkscaggGLXq/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .extensions import *
  File "/tmp/.mount_InkscaggGLXq/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/extensions.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .elements import (
  File "/tmp/.mount_InkscaggGLXq/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/elements/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._parser import SVG_PARSER, load_svg
  File "/tmp/.mount_InkscaggGLXq/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/elements/_parser.py", line 30, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined symbol: __libc_unwind_link_get, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

This my config -
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Python 3.12.0 (set using pyenv global)
lxml==5.2.1

I also have the librt.so file in my system and it does have the symbol mentioned in the error using nm -gDC librt.so.1.
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.3.3
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.3.4
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.4
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.7
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U __libc_fatal@GLIBC_PRIVATE
                 U __libc_unwind_link_get@GLIBC_PRIVATE
0000000000001140 T __librt_version_placeholder@GLIBC_2.3.4
0000000000001140 T __librt_version_placeholder@GLIBC_2.7
0000000000001140 T __librt_version_placeholder@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001140 T __librt_version_placeholder@GLIBC_2.3.3
0000000000001140 T __librt_version_placeholder@GLIBC_2.4

Is the error with the lxml library? The Python version? Is Inkscape using a different Python environment? Maybe something to do with system packages?
I'm grateful for any help in figuring this out.
